# Magento 2.3.2: How to delete custom table column

Tags: magento2.3, declarative-schema

I have created Custom Table Using below code. Table has been created successfully with columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Custom Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="inc_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Title"/>
         <column xsi:type="varchar" name="subtitle" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Subtitle"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" name="PRIMARY">
            <column name="inc_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

But when i try to remove the column by removing the subtitle column, It doesn't get deleted.My Updated Xml looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
     <table name="custom_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Custom Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="inc_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Title"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" name="PRIMARY">
            <column name="inc_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

I have run following command after removing the column from xml,which created db_schema_whitelist.json in etc folder.

```
$ bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist [options]
```

Finally upgrade command.

```
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: u may check https://github.com/bdcrops/BDC_Declarative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to found it myself, we can delete those column by using disabled="true" property.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Custom Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="inc_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Title" disabled="true"/>
         <column xsi:type="varchar" name="subtitle" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Subtitle" disabled="true"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" name="PRIMARY">
            <column name="inc_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

After that run the command

```
$ bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use dropColumn script:

```
$setup->getConnection()->dropColumn($setup->getTable('your_table'), 'your_column');
```

doing with UpgradeSchema.php is a better and cleaner solution

Please check.

Comment: can't we remove the column using xml itself?

Comment: I searched, but not found column delete from the xml. This the way I know. You can use.

Comment: Thanks,  I just searched and found out we need to use disabled="true" against column that we need to delete.

Comment: I deleted it by using <column xsi:type="varchar" name="subtitle" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Subtitle" diabled="true"/>

Comment: Ohh, great. you can add it as the answer. So might it will help someone.

Comment: ok bro, Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try to revert your db_schema.xml file and run `$ bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist` again, then remove the column, change module version number to a higher one and then run `$ bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: Do we need to change module version? I thought they have mentioned that for previous magento versions where we use installschema , upgradeschema

Comment: I've didn't tested but in logic it is needed.

Comment: @krybbio no, using db_schema altering the tables will not needed change in module versioning